# REST API and eager loading rested resources

Tags: rest

Imagine a resource such as Authors. An Author has multiple books, multiple pictures, etc.

In some pages of my app, I only need the surface author data such as name. In other pages, I need all the nested resources as well. How do I handle the loading of nested resources?

1. Do I load everything in one call such that: 
   GET /authors returns {
      name: x,
      books: {
        bookname: a,
         ...
      }
    }
2. Accept an optional parameter that specifies the nested objects, such as: 
   GET /authors?include=books&pictures
3. Return just the surface author data then fetch the related resources in subsequent calls. However, this could lead to n+1 type queries, such as: 
   GET /authors 
   GET /author/1/images
   GET /author/1/books

Any insight appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the following REST-style URLs:

GET /authors  - to get list of all authors

GET /authors/{authorId} - basic info about the concrete author in one request

GET /authors/{authorId}/detailed - detailed info about the concrete author in one request

Additionally, you could have the following methods to extract specific info about author:

GET /authors/{authorId}/images - get all images by author

GET /authors/{authorId}/images/{imageId} - get one image by author

GET /authors/{authorId}/books - get all books by author

GET /authors/{authorId}/books/{bookId} - get one book by author

Also I recommend to read REST resource naming conventions [here](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html).

Comment: that does seem like the cleanest approach. I guess I shouldn't worry about the potential performance penalty until its an actual issue?

Comment: @recipherus, clients of your REST service would probably expect most of operations listed above(except _GET /authors/{authorId}/detailed_) to be present in your API. But nothing wrong to add methods that will optimize some calls. Just like in your example: _GET /authors/{authorId}/detailed?include=books&pictures_. So, you could combine your 2 & 3 approaches to get balance of clean REST & performance.